# How to merge tasks in firestore to create AND query?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is for `OR` query tasks

Please tell me how to convert this into `AND` query?

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    CollectionReference learnings = db.collection("learnings");

    Task task1 = learnings.whereLessThan("l_fee", MaximumRequiredPrice)
            .get();

    Task task2 = learnings.whereLessThan("l_duration", MaximumRequiredDuration)
            .get();

    Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> allTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task1, task2);
    allTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
            for (QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : querySnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Learning learning = documentSnapshot.toObject(Learning.class);
                    result.add(learning);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that you have 2 Tasks when you only need one with the 'where' clauses added:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference learnings = db.collection("learnings");

Task task1 = learnings.whereLessThan("l_fee", MaximumRequiredPrice)
        .whereLessThan("l_duration", MaximumRequiredDuration)
        .get();
```